# Google Oauth 2 does not work when deployed behind a domain

Tags: reactjs, nginx, oauth, dns, devops

I have a react app that uses google oauth2, the application works as expected locally, but fails to authenticate returning a 403 when deployed on a VM behind a reverse proxy, and accessed using a domain name.

For some reason, it returns a 403 on the auth request.

Any guides on how to deploy something like this

I have added the domain in the oauth creds screen in JS origins and redirect URIs.